# Ubuntu 16.04 Installed on RAID 0 with mdadm followed by boot repair still fails to boot

Tags: boot, raid, grubrescue, boot-repair, mdadm

My Ubuntu 16.04 was installed successfully with ubiquity --no-bootloader.  Then, I ran boot-repair and rebooted.  My computer still failed to reboot.

My boot-repair paste is this: http://paste2.org/9DZsPb9A

My failed-to-boot grub rescue looks like the below image.

[image]

I've been searching a lot and no solution solves my issue.  Could someone please help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. When booting check the boot order (f8 or f10 my memory is a bit flaky). I found that the boot order had changed from the drive with the OS to one of the Raid drives. I have my OS on a separate disk from the raid array. if it has changed, you will need to change to the drive that the OS is on.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

My computer is a Dell Dimension 5150 and I needed to go to the bios menu and do two things to solve this issue.

(1) Under Drives, make sure each drive is set to "On", not "Off".

(2) In SATA Operation, make sure it's set to "RAID On", not "RAID Autodetect / ATA"

Anyway, thanks pipin for sharing your comment.